# python module is not found after successfully installed using $ pip3 install --user

Tags: python, bash, module, installation, pip

I tried to install Selenium on my mac using `pip3 install selenium`, but it created an error of "Permission denied". So I tried `pip3 install --user selenium`, and it did install perfectly.

However, the paths are probably different as my PyCharm interpreter can't find the Selenium module.

```
$ pip3 install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages
```

The problem is, the path doesn't even exist in my mac, I can only find `/Library/Python/2.7/`. Thus, I cannot just drag the module into the correct site-package.

The correct path should be `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

How do I change the order of the path? And should I change it and reinstall selenium again? Thanks.

Comment: Try installing from inside pycharm...

Comment: @StephenRauch It works. Thank you.